# How to select data in Cassandra either by ID or date?

Tags: cassandra

I have a very simple data table. But after reading a lot of examples in the internet, I am still more and more confused how to solve the following scenario:

**1) The Table**

My data table looks like this (without defining the primayr key, as this is my understanding problem):

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
    uid text,
    created text,
    data text
}
```

Now my goal is to have to different ways to select data.

**2) Select by the UID:**

```
SELECT * FROM documents
    WHERE uid = ‘xxxx-yyyyy-zzzz’
```

**3) Select by a date limit**

```
SELECT * FROM documents
    WHERE created >= ‘2015-06-05’
```

So my question is:

What should my table definition in Cassandra look like, so that I can perform these selections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve both queries, you would need two tables.
First one would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
    uid text,
    created text,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid));
```

and you retrieve your data with: `SELECT * FROM documents WHERE uid='xxxx-yyyy-zzzzz'` Of course, uid must be unique. You might want to consider the uuid data type (instead of text)

Second one is more delicate. If you set your partition to the full date, you won't be able to do a range query, as range query is only available on the clustering column. So you need to find the sweet spot for your partition key in order to:

1. make sure a single partition won't be too large (max 100MB,
   otherwise you will run into trouble)
2. satisfy your query requirements.

As an example:

```
CREATE TABLE documents_by_date (
    year int,
    month int,
    day int,
    uid text,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((year, month), day, uid);
```

This works fine if within a day, you don't have too many documents (so your partition don't grow too much). And this allows you to create queries such as: `SELECT * FROM documents_by_date WHERE year=2018 and month=12 and day>=6 and day<=24;` If you need to issue a range query across multiple months, you will need to issue multiple queries.
If your partition is too large due to the `data` field, you will need to remove it from documents_by_date. And use `documents` table to retrieve the data, given the uid you retreived from `documents_by_date`.
If your partition is still too large, you will need to add `hour` in the partition key of `documents_by_date`.

So overall, it's not a straightforward request, and you will need to find the right balance for yourself when defining your partition key.

If latency is not a huge concern, an alternative would be to use the stratio lucene cassandra plugin, and index your date.

Comment: First table cannot have more than one document per user as the Primary key is only UID.

Comment: I am currently assuming that the meaning behind uid is "unique id". If the meaning is "user id", then it definitely needs change.

Comment: Ok - to make it more clear. 
UID is a unique id form another system. I need this key to fetch exactly one specific data entry. So the first table is clear. 

The creation date is for fetching data without knowing the UID. One document takes 1 - 100 MB. So I understand that the documents_by_date table should not duplicate the data column - right? 

From the select statement it would be acceptable to select by exact Year/Month or by exact Year/Month/Day. So for the second table the partition should be always below 100MB for this table.  
 
So did you suggest to use 2 tables?

Comment: Storing large files in Cassandra ( larger than a few MB) is not really advised. Can you store it in a separate filesystem and keep the link / url in Cassandra? AWS S3 is a good example. Also, remember that a Cassandra node density should not go above 2TB, storing large file makes it very expensive. You still need 2 tables to achieve your 2 queries. If you use one table with ALLOW FILTERING in prod, you will have poor performance and no scalability.

Answer (score 1):

Question does not specify how your data is going to be with respect user and create time. But since its a document, I am assuming that one user will be creating one document at one "created" time.

Below is the table definition you can use.

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
    uid text,
    created text,
    data text
    PRIMARY KEY (uid, created)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC);
```

*WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC)* can help you get the data order by created for a given user.

For your first requirement you can query like given below.

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE uid = 'SEARCH_UID';
```

For your second requirement you can query like given below

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE created > '2018-04-10 11:32:00' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Use of Allow Filtering should be used diligently as it scans all partitions. If we have to create a separate table with date as primary key, it becomes tricky if there are many documents being inserted at very same second. Clustering order works best for the requirements where documents for a given user need to be sorted by time.

Comment: The uid is a unique identifier and not user specific. My source is a workflow system which is archiving data into the table. Each document entry is unique. But the creation date is important to select archive data form a specific point of time.

Comment: As the uid is a unique identifier and the data can be between 1 and 100 MB per record. Would you think one table is still a good solution? Or should I separate the date into a second table? It would also be  acceptable to select for a specific day or month only. So I need not really a greater/lower select statement. What do you think?

Comment: Ah I see. If it's not user specific, then keeping only that as a PRIMARY KEY is fine. Considering that you have a flexibility in requirement to fetch by specific date, I think it makes more sense to go with 2 table approach which Christophe has suggested.

But for simplicity, I would suggest to use epoch time instead of year and month.

CREATE TABLE documents_by_date (
    create_time bigint,
    uid text,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (create_time,uid);

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will go with the two tables.